Amazon SP API: Listing Update Accepted but Not Reflecting on Live Listing
I have been working on updating product listings using the Amazon Selling Partner API. I'm sending a PATCH request to update the item_name of a product. The API response indicates that my request has been accepted with the status "ACCEPTED", but the changes are not reflecting on the live listing in Seller Central. Here's the API call and response:
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/listings/2020-09-01/items/seller/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx?sellerId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&sku=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&marketplaceIds=xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "productType": "MECHANICAL_LIGHTER",
    "patches": [
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "path": "/attributes/item_name/0/value/0",
            "value": "test name"
        }
    ]
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'x-amz-access-token: Your-Access-Token-Here'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;


{
    "sku": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "submissionId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "issues": []
}


Problem:
Despite receiving the "status": "ACCEPTED" response, the updated item_name is not appearing on the live listing. It only shows up in the editable title box in Seller Central, but the live listing remains unchanged.

Checked for Processing Time: I waited for some time and refreshed the listing page, but the changes are still not reflecting.
Verified JSON Path: I ensured that the JSON path is correct and matches Amazon's API documentation.
Manual Update: I tried manually updating the listing through Seller Central, and it worked immediately, which indicates that the API request might be missing something.

My Questions:

Is there something wrong with the way I'm structuring the API request?
Could there be a delay in the listing update, and if so, how long should I expect to wait?
Are there any specific requirements or constraints I should be aware of when using the Amazon SP API for updating product listings?
How can I troubleshoot this issue further, given that the API response doesn't indicate any errors?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!


Did you manage to figure it out?
